# Can't access to database create by other app android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I work on a project with two applications. The first enable to record information on database and the second use this information.
I have no problem for the first but when I try access to the database with the second, I have the error :

> 08-05 14:22:29.545: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-05 14:22:29.545: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
>   matable (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM
>   matable
>   08-05 14:22:29.545: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):
>     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method) 08-05 14:22:29.545: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
>   08-05 14:22:29.545: E/AndroidRuntime(4751): ...

I have set on the two manifest the variable   `android:sharedUserId="mySharedUserId"`
I have link my first app to my second app to reuse the class of the first app (DataBaseHelper, DAO, ...). It is the same code which is execute to acces (write or read) to the database.
My DataBaseHelper.java

```
package com.mypackage.database;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

    public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String TAG = "DataBaseHelper";
        private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
        private final Context myContext;

        private static  int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        private static  String DATABASE_NAME = "db_devicesManager";
        private String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.mypackage.myapp/databases/";

        public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            Log.d(TAG, "path :"+DATABASE_PATH);
            this.myContext = context; 
        }

        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {       
            boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase(); 
            if(!mDataBaseExist) 
            { 
                this.getReadableDatabase(); 
                this.close(); 
                try  
                { 
                    copyDataBase(); 
                }  
                catch (IOException mIOException)  
                { 
                    throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase"); 
                } 
            } 
        }

        private boolean checkDataBase() {
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            try{
                String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            }catch(SQLiteException e){
                //database does't exist yet.
            }

            if(checkDB != null){
                checkDB.close();
            }

            return checkDB != null ? true : false;

        }


        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
            InputStream inputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
            String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(myPath);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }

        public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
            String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY); 
            return myDataBase!=null;
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {

            if (myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();
            super.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }
```

I  have tried to uninstall apps, change version of database unsuccessfully.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

**First**: Do not use hardcoded paths. Use [`Context.getDatabasePath(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) instead.

**Second**: If the data you want is inside another application, then that application needs to expose an interface for you to communicate across process boundaries. Typically this means the serving app (the one with the data) implements either a [`ContentProvider`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) or a [`Bound Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html), the latter might possibly require the use of [`AIDL`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Context.getDatabasePath(String) should be use when I open database ? ( SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Context.getDatabasePath(myPath),null) ). I don't know ContentProvider or BoundService, I will search on this way. For the moment I use the pattern DAO, is it possible to use this pattern with ContentProvider ?

Comment: If the database belongs to your app, you should use a `SQLiteOpenHelper` and call it's `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()` methods. If the database belongs to another app, then you cannot open that file yourself because it is protected with file permissions by the system, and that is why the owning app needs to provide a `ContentProvider` or Bound Service to facilitate interprocess communication. How you implement actual data manipulation behind those interfaces is entirely up to you.